# Fetchall возвращает пустой список SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, select, sqlite3

Пытаюсь вытянуть значения из базы данных, но получаю пустой список. Вот код:

```
with sqlite3.connect('db.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM skins")
    skins = cursor.fetchall()
    print(skins)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модуль sqlite3 импортирован, в базе есть значения (скриншот выше), но почему-то результат не получаю. При чём эта же команда SELECT работает и получает необходимые поля, если вводить её в DB Browser. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

P.S. перенёс данную конструкцию в другой файл, всё работает. Если что этот код находится в асинхронной функции. Могут ли быть с этим проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что файл db.db находится в той же директории, что и файл, в котором запрос работал. Как только поменял путь на `items/db.db`, всё заработало. Будьте внимательны